# cannot create a text file in C++

Tags: c++, text, window, fstream

I'm using an `ofstream` object to create and print a string to a text file, but it doesn't work. this is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namesace std;
int main()
{
     ofstream output("d:\\data.txt");
     output << "this is my text" << endl;
     output.close();
     return 0;
}
```

The file `data.txt` was created when I set `output("data.txt")`. The text file was created in the same folder that contains the source code. But when I set `output(d:\\data.txt)` or any other location, it was not created at all. This code has also worked well in other computer and the problem only occurs in my laptop. I'm using visual stdio 2013 and operated by 
Windows 10 pro.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is stop using `void main()`. Next, check the permission.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a file manually in `d:\\`, then get the complete, *correct* directory of the file from its properties. That way, you will know any mistakes you are making in specifying the directory of the file to be created.

Comment: This kind of helpful advice (that is maybe-but-not-really a solution) should be posted as a *comment*, not an answer. Also, please do not use inline code formatting to emphasize text. Use bold or italics, instead.

Comment: thank Jarvis, I figured out that window 10 does not allow us to create a new text directedly in a harddrive without a specific directory.

Comment: Glad to know...If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted :) @TrầnNgọcDũng